# Why is my div centered by default and won't cooperate when trying to horizontally align it?

Tags: html, css

The div seems to center without me doing anything to center it and when I try to move it left or right, it won't cooperate very well at all and seems impossible to horizontally align. I don't understand why it starts out in the middle and I don't understand why doing things such as "margin-left:-10px" won't move it to the left at all.

```
*{
    margin:0 auto;
}

#main_cont {
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:#CFA759;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-left:-10px;
}
```

Comment: Did any of the answers below answer your question? If so, will you please mark the most useful answer as "accepted"? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're setting auto-center margin on everything with this CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Remove that CSS, and rework your styling to apply auto-center margin only on the elements you need it on.

Answer (score 0):

You've set all elements in the page to be horizontally centered with the code up the top:

```
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you really need that there, then you could set `position: absolute` which would make the element's position relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static - [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). So depending on the rest of your code, you should be okay.